# How to remove all instances of a duplicate from a vector<int>

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, stdvector

I've been trying to solve an "easy" leetcode question for two hours now where I need to remove every instance of an int that appears more than once then add the non dupes together. I've tried about 10 different ways and I can only get it to go down to one copy of each int. Here is the nicest solution I've written, but given input {1,2,2,3,4} it would return {1,2,3,4} whereas the expected output is {1,3,4}

```
  sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); //Sort numerically
  nums.erase(unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()), nums.end()); 
  return (accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0));
```

Comment: unique only removes non-unique! hence `{2,2}` -> `{2}`

Comment: Then I guess the next step is to come up with a different plan, as the one you have now will not work.  That's how the game of programming and being a programmer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NlogN` complexity, you avoid needing to pre-sort:

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:24,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:24,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:24,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:24),source:%27%0A%23include+%3Cset%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Avoid+myFunc()%0A%7B%0A++++vector%3Cint%3E+nums+%3D+%7B1,2,2,3,5%7D%3B%0A%0A++++multiset%3Cint%3E+m+(nums.begin(),+nums.end())%3B%0A%0A++++std::size_t+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(const+auto%26+elem+:+m)%0A++++%7B%0A++++sum+%2B%3D+m.count(elem)+%3D%3D+1+%3F+elem+:+0%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sum+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++myFunc()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.28727612542895,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.620151213375685,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:54.71272387457105,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {1,2,2,3,5};

    std::multiset<int> m (nums.begin(), nums.end());

    std::size_t sum = 0;
    for (const auto& elem : m)
    {
      sum += m.count(elem) == 1 ? elem : 0;
    }
}
```

---

Update: Could use `std::unordered_multiset`, as we don't need ordering.

Comment: I'm new to the whole Log timing but this one runs pretty quickly and works great. Thankyou

Comment: Shall do, just replying to other comments first

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::unordered_map<int, bool>` where the second (template) parameter (`bool`) specifies whether the value is duplicated or not. It'll look something like this,

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
...

std::unordered_map<int, bool> uniqueCheckMap;
for (auto i : nums)
{
    if (uniqueCheckMap.find(i) == uniqueCheckMap.end())
        uniqueCheckMap[i] = false;
    else
        uniqueCheckMap[i] = true;    // Set the second (value) as true if duplicate entry is found.
}

nums.clear();
int sum = 0;
for (auto i : uniqueCheckMap)
{
    if (!i.second)
    {
        nums.push_back(i.first);
        sum += i.first;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rename `map` to something else.  Also, the OP wanted to add up the values, not copy them into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

There are many workarounds, you can iterate over the array and see how many time the number exists using `map` or something, and then you iterate again over the map and add the number that only appeared once to a new array.
You can use a set and a `map<bool,int>`, every time you add a new number you check if it exists or not.

```
if(!map[number]){
set.insert(number);
map[number]=true;
}else{
set.erase(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If O(n²) is not a problem...

```
const auto sum=std::accumulate(cbegin(nums), cend(nums), 0,
  [&](const auto &accum, const auto &elem)
  {
    return accum+(std::count(cbegin(nums), cend(nums), elem)>1 ? 0 : elem);
  });
```

Comment: Works great and nice lambda function. Works in my IDE but not leetcode, I think it's not the right version of C++

Answer (score 1):

[`set_difference`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) is a great help here.  It removes occurences in the way you describe.

```
        auto ints = vector{4, 3, 2, 2, 1};

        sort(begin(ints), end(ints));
        std::vector<int> unique_ints;
        unique_copy(begin(ints), end(ints), back_inserter(unique_ints));

        vector<int> doubles;
        set_difference( begin(ints), end(ints),
                        begin(unique_ints), end(unique_ints),
                        back_inserter(doubles)
                        );

        vector<int> only_once;
        set_difference( begin(unique_ints), end(unique_ints),
                        begin(doubles), end(doubles),
                        back_inserter(only_once));

        copy(begin(only_once), end(only_once), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
        cout << "\n";
```

Also... it seems to do the trick.

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++17 u.cpp  && ./a.out 
1, 3, 4,
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a loop over 'equal ranges', only accumulating the ones that are a single element long:

```
        sort(begin(ints), end(ints));

        int acc = 0;
        auto range = equal_range(begin(ints), end(ints), ints.front());

        while(range.first != end(ints)) {
                cout << *range.first << "+ ";
                if (distance(range.first, range.second) == 1){
                        acc += *range.first;
                }
                range = equal_range(range.second, end(ints), *range.second);
        }
        cout << " = " << acc << "\n";
```