# C++ - Find sum of unique elements

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the sum of unique elements, however I am not meeting the requirements of the given output.

```
//Prompted Input: [1,2,3,2]
//Expected output: 4
//Explanation: The unique elements are [1,3]
```

Below is my relevant code. Some things I have tried was to set j to i for the nested loop, however that changed nothing. The next step I took was to take out the first if conditional and have the code do the sum after finding the unique numbers but the output was 10. I'd be grateful if someone could give me a direction of where I'm messing up because I know I am close.

```
int sumOfUnique(vector<int>& nums) {

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(j == i){
                    sum += nums[i];
                }
                if(nums[i] == nums[j]){
                    break;
                }
            }
                
        }    
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Try sorting the array first (so all elements that occur more than once are consecutive), then loop through once adding up elements that are not adjacent (before or after) an element equal to itself.   The trade-off is a need to store a copy of `nums`, which can be achieved simply by passing it by value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all instances of a duplicate from a vector<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122085/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-a-duplicate-from-a-vectorint). They also attempted to accumulate the unique elements in a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You're close in that you have nested loops, but the content of the loops is not correct. The key is that you need to identify the unique elements, that's not something that your current code does.

Use the inner loop to identify if an element is unique and then after the inner loop add it to the sum if it is. Like this

```
int sumOfUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        // count how many times nums[i] occurs
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++)
            if (nums[i] == nums[j])
                ++count;
        if (count == 1)     // is nums[i] unique?
            sum += nums[i]; // add it to the sum if it is
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The trick is the extra variable `count` to work out if a particular number is unique.

You can make this code clearer and more flexible by putting the uniqueness test into it's own function. Like this

```
bool isUnique(vector<int>& nums, int i) {
    // count how many times nums[i] occurs
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++)
        if (nums[i] == nums[j])
            ++count;
    // return true if it occurs once only
    return count == 1;
}

int sumOfUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (isUnique(nums, i))  // is nums[i] unique?
            sum += nums[i];     // add it to the sum if it is
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It's good to split code into different functions, with each function solving one part of the puzzle. Now (for instance) you could replace `isUnique` with a different function and sum values in your vector based on some different criterion.

There are more efficient solutions that this using `std::set` but I expect that the point of this exercise is to get you practising with loops and algorithms.

Comment: Thank you! All of this helps a lot and yes this is for practicing with loops and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map` to create a frequency counter. After that, iterate through the map and check if a number only occurred once. If that's true, add that number to the result and afterward print out the final result.

```
int uniqueSum(vector<int> numbers)
{
    map<int, int> frequency;
    for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it!=numbers.end(); it++)
    {
        int value = (*it);
        if (frequency.find(value) == frequency.end()) {frequency[value] = 1;}
        else {frequency[value]++;}

        //if value already occur in map then add 1 to its counter, 
        //else set its counter to 1
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto it = frequency.begin(); it!=frequency.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->second == 1) {sum += it->first; } 
        //if the element appear just once in the vector, add it to sum, else skip it
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can read more about map here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

And also the find() function: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Answer (score -1):

Use a `map` to store numbers you have seen, and if they repeat, mark as not-viable.

```
int sumOfUnique(std::vector<int>& nums)
{
  std::map<int, bool> seen;
  for (auto i : nums)
  {
    auto it = seen.find(i);
    if (it != seen.end()) // If already exists, set viability to false
    { 
      it->second = false; 
    }
    else { seen.insert({ i, true }); } // Does not exist, is currently viable
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (auto pair : seen)
  {
    if (pair.second) // If viable
    {
      sum += pair.first;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not produce the desired output. Note that for the given input `{1, 2, 3, 2}`, the output should be `1 + 3 = 4`, not `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`.

Comment: @NathanPierson I just realized that, will fix it.